# IE некорректно отображает отчет Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

В IE (11я версия) некорректно отображается текст в колонке 5, точнее не работает выравнивание.

[Скрин IE](http://prntscr.com/ldkcmm)

В Report Builder визуально все корректно, выравнивание настроено по аналогии с соседними ячейками

[Скрин RB](http://prntscr.com/ldkc2g)

В чем может быть проблема?

UPD - скрин из 
[Firefox](http://prntscr.com/lew4zs)

**UPD2:** По версии RS точно не подскажу. Установлена та, что идет вместе с SQL Server 2008 R2.

Код этой ячейки+соседних:

```
<TablixCornerCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Textbox384">
                    <CanShrink>true</CanShrink>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>В рабочее время</Value>
                            <Style>
                              <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                              <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                            </Style>
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style>
                          <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
                        </Style>
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox384</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <TopBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </TopBorder>
                      <BottomBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </BottomBorder>
                      <LeftBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </LeftBorder>
                      <RightBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </RightBorder>
                      <BackgroundColor>CornflowerBlue</BackgroundColor>
                      <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      <WritingMode>Rotate270</WritingMode>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCornerCell>
              <TablixCornerCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Textbox6">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>Звонки, поступившие в очередь</Value>
                            <Style>
                              <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                              <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                            </Style>
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style>
                          <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
                        </Style>
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox6</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <TopBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </TopBorder>
                      <BottomBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </BottomBorder>
                      <LeftBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </LeftBorder>
                      <RightBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </RightBorder>
                      <BackgroundColor>CornflowerBlue</BackgroundColor>
                      <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      <WritingMode>Rotate270</WritingMode>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                  <rd:Selected>true</rd:Selected>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCornerCell>
              <TablixCornerCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Textbox420">
                    <CanShrink>true</CanShrink>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>Вне часов работы</Value>
                            <Style>
                              <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                              <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                            </Style>
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style>
                          <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
                        </Style>
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox420</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <TopBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </TopBorder>
                      <BottomBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </BottomBorder>
                      <LeftBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </LeftBorder>
                      <RightBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </RightBorder>
                      <BackgroundColor>CornflowerBlue</BackgroundColor>
                      <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      <WritingMode>Rotate270</WritingMode>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
```

Comment: Скорее всего дело в вёрстке, ie славится своей поддержкой css. Скорее всего microsoft теперь поддерживает Edge и не правит баги для поддержки в других браузерах. Попробуйте открыть в edge (если есть).

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev так выглядит в Firefox http://prntscr.com/lew4zs

Comment: ну да, проблема в кроссбраузерной вёрстке. Видимо отчёт это не учитывает, либо майкрософт забил.

Comment: Могу только посоветовать написать на англоязычный stackoverflow (там выше шанс, что ответят). И потом сюда решение опубликуйте.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev дело в том, что для соседних ячеек форматирование настроено аналогичным образом - и с ними все в порядке:(

Comment: Проще всего тупо на js поиграть с стилем для данной ячейки, т.е. для ie менять margin, overflow, возможно даже поставить position:relative и поменять позицию. В общем, Поворот текста - больная тема. Нужно для ie писать один скрипт поворота, для не ie - другой. Пробуйте или сss или js написать такой патч к повороту, который будет работать корректно. Я в свое время потратил дня три что б добится хорошего отображения.

Comment: @nick_n_a дело в том, что поворот задается всего одним свойством в Report Builder. Можно каким-то образом управлять стилями вне свойств Report Builder?

Comment: Конечно можно. Нужно взять страницу где рендерится, и добавить туда CSS либо JS видя html соурс "того что вышло" Если используете asp - проблем нет. Если не используете, то асп лежит тут  *c:\program files\Microsoft SQL server\MSSQL.4\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages\ReportView.aspx* у меня 4, у вас может быть другая цифра.

Comment: В данном вопросе не хватает двух деталей: 1)как строки оформлены в rdl/rdlc файле. Возможно анализ самой xml (rdl=xml) даст ответ на вопрос "почему разные". 2)показан рисунок, но не показан html который за ним стоит, возможно из этого html можно сделать вывод. 3) Да, интересно, а если нарисовать новый шаблон с нуля - проблема повторяется (типа rdl-заглючило)?

Comment: Какая версия Reporting Services? Добавление сайта в список отображаемых в режиме совместимости в IE что нибудь меняет?

Comment: @nick_n_a добавил код этой ячейки и соседних

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight добавил в список совместимости - осталось все так же

Comment: А какой номер проблемной textbox?

Comment: @nick_n_a Textbox6

Comment: C rdl проблем не вижу... Наверно что-то в html не получилось, попробуйте "исследовать елемент" (проверить елемент в ie называется), но если и в html проблем нету - то это сугубо глюк ie, который можно... разве что "патчить" накладками через стиль.

Comment: @nick_n_a если бы проблема была только в IE, то вопрос и не задавал бы:) но и тот же Firefox ведет себя неадекватно с этой ячейкой:( Но, скорее всего, как и думал изначально, проблема в использовании старой версии RS

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю взять, посмотреть исходный код, и пропачить его. Если используете asp - проблем нет. Если не используете, то aspx лежит тут `c:\program files\Microsoft SQL server\MSSQL.4\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages\ReportView.aspx` у меня 4, у вас может быть другая цифра. Путь может немного отличатся, но где-то такой.

Посмотрим что нагенерировал report сервер

```
<table id="ReportViewerControl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr style="HEIGHT:27.50mm">
     <td class="a34 r5 r7 r8"><div class="r11">Cтолбец 1</div></td>
     <td class="a35 r7 r8"><div class="r11">Столбец 2</div></td>
```

Соответственно тут два варианта. JS, CSS,  JS+CSS

Покажу вариант с JS

Берём наш ReportView.aspx (либо ваш aspx с контролом отчёта) и допиливаем

```
  ...<html>
  <RS:ReportViewrHost ID="..." >
  </form>
  // Cуда вставим наш код
  <script type="text/javascript" >
  if (условие_на_иe11)
  // Для всех отчётов используется один файл, отличить отчёты можно по location вверху браузера.
  //ReportViewer.aspx?%2fProject%2fMyReport1  у меня такой
  if (location.href.IndexOf("?Название-Отчета-С-Папкой") > 0 ) {
     // Патчим
     var tab = document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl");
     var row = tab.rows[0];
     var elm = row.firstChild;
     elm = elm.nextSibling;
     elm = elm.nextSibling;         
     elm.style = "Стиль";         
      }
 </script>
```

В стиль нужно добавить margin padding и т.п. что сместить надпись "наместо".

Не лучший вариант, но результат даст. Если не получается - нужно вызывать alert или console.log. Я пачил страницы отчётов, когда "красоту требовали" (добавлял название отчёта перед таблицей).

P.S. Вероятно что ответ на вопрос нужно вытрушивать у mіcrosoft или на их форумах, возможно в новой версии ReportServer эту проблему исправят.

UDP: И вопросы... как вопрос-вариант решения:

1)посмотреть как оформлены строки в rdl/rdlc файле. Возможно анализ самой xml (rdl=xml) даст ответ на вопрос "почему разные". Редактор rdlc-отчета может "не отображать" отличия. Возможно какой-то xml-атрибут лишний. Сравнить две ветки для двух столбцов вида `<Textbox Name="textbox19">`.

2)показана таблица, но не показана её html-код, а лучше два отличия в "исследовать елемент" (вроде в ие11 такое уже есть.  Возможно это отличие натолкнёт на мысль что не так.

3) Если нарисовать новый шаблон с нуля - проблема повторяется (типа rdl-заглючило) или решается?